# "cc1plus: error: bad value (‘tigerlake’) for ‘-march=’ switch" compilation error

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors, compilation, openframeworks

```
cc1plus: error: bad value (‘tigerlake’) for ‘-march=’ switch

cc1plus: note: valid arguments to ‘-march=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 cannonlake icelake-client icelake-server cascadelake bonnell atom silvermont slm goldmont goldmont-plus tremont knl knm x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 znver2 btver1 btver2 native

cc1plus: error: bad value (‘tigerlake’) for ‘-mtune=’ switch

cc1plus: note: valid arguments to ‘-mtune=’ switch are: nocona core2 nehalem corei7 westmere sandybridge corei7-avx ivybridge core-avx-i haswell core-avx2 broadwell skylake skylake-avx512 cannonlake icelake-client icelake-server cascadelake bonnell atom silvermont slm goldmont goldmont-plus tremont knl knm intel x86-64 eden-x2 nano nano-1000 nano-2000 nano-3000 nano-x2 eden-x4 nano-x4 k8 k8-sse3 opteron opteron-sse3 athlon64 athlon64-sse3 athlon-fx amdfam10 barcelona bdver1 bdver2 bdver3 bdver4 znver1 znver2 btver1 btver2 generic native

make[2]: *** [makefileCommon/compile.core.mk:240: /home/josue/Documents/of_v0.11.0_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/obj/Release/libs/openFrameworks/events/ofEvents.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [makefileCommon/compile.core.mk:204: Release] Error 2

make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/josue/Documents/of_v0.11.0_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project'
make: *** [/home/josue/Documents/of_v0.11.0_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/project/makefileCommon/compile.project.mk:125: Release] Error 2
```

Whenever I try to compile using make command in the terminal I get this error. Program compiles and runs fine on my old laptop and my desktop. Using openframeworks library. I'm using the XPS 13 9310 which has a tigerlake processor which the error mentions. XPS is running Pop!_OS same as my desktop. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which compiler and version are you using?

Comment: Just to be clear the error is not because your computer has the wrong processor in it.  The error is because your _compiler_ doesn't recognize that option.  Most likely your compiler is too old to support this.  Run `gcc --version` to see the version and `gcc --target-help` and search the output for the `-mtune` option to see which CPUs your version of the compiler supports.

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
I tried running apt update/upgrade and apt install I guess packages are out of date. I'll try installing it from elsewhere to see if it helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved installing g++-10 and gcc-10 using:

```
sudo apt install g++-10
sudo apt install gcc-10
```

then running make with:

```
make CC=gcc-10 CPP=g++-10 CXX=g++-10 LD=g++-10
```

Thanks to Retired Ninja and MadScientist.

Answer (score 24):

You can update gcc&g++ to a higher version(10):

```
sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
```

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-10 100 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-10 --slave /usr/bin/gcov gcov /usr/bin/gcov-10
```

then you can choose the default gcc version with the following order:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

ref: https://www.cnblogs.com/livelab/p/13049117.html

Comment: This should de the accepted answer. (The accepted answer is not working).